# JAXB serialization in two subelements

Tags: java, jaxb

Class:

```
public class OddEvenSettings {
  int oddSetting1;
  int oddSetting2;
  int evenSetting1;
  int evenSetting2;
}
```

Desired XML

```
<OddEvenSettings>
  <odd setting1="0" setting2="0"/>
  <even setting1="0" setting2="0"/>
</OddEvenSettings>
```

How should I annotate the class to get the XML after serialization (using JAXB RI)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You could use MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension for this use case:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.*;

@XmlRootElement("OddEvenSettings")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class OddEvenSettings {
  @XmlPath("odd/@setting1")
  int oddSetting1;

  @XmlPath("odd/@setting2")
  int oddSetting2;

  @XmlPath("even/@setting1")
  int evenSetting1;

  @XmlPath("even/@setting2")
  int evenSetting2;
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: Good argument to change the JAXB provider

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to create 2 new classes 'OddSettings' and 'EvenSettings' and to reference 'OddEvenSettings' to 'OddSettings' and 'EvenSettings' like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="OddEvenSettings")
public class OddEvenSettings {

    @XmlElement(name="odd")
    private OddSetting oddSetting = new OddSetting();

    @XmlElement(name="even")
    private EvenSetting evenSetting = new EvenSetting();

        ...
}
```

Of course `OddSettings` and `EvenSettings` should be annotated too:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class OddSetting {
    @XmlAttribute(name="setting1")
    int oddSetting1;
    @XmlAttribute(name="setting2")
    int oddSetting2;
        ...
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class EvenSetting {
    @XmlAttribute(name="setting1")
    int evenSetting1;
    @XmlAttribute(name="setting2")
    int evenSetting2;
        ...
}
```

This produces what you need:

```
<OddEvenSettings>
    <odd setting1="0" setting2="0"/>
    <even setting1="0" setting2="0"/>
</OddEvenSettings>
```